# How to integrate Django model and form with my view

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I integrate my html to my form and model so that it can process the backend. In admin page, everything works fine but I'm unable to integrate it with my frontend.
**This is my models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class SignUp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**This is my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['name', 'email']

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')

        return name 

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        try:
            match = SignUp.objects.get(email=email)
        except SignUp.DoesNotExist:
            return email

        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already subscribed.')
```

**This is my view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings 

from .forms import SignUpForm

def signUp(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.clean_name()
        email = form.clean_email()
        instance = form.save()

        subject = 'Bruke Church news'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = [email]
        contact_message = "%s:Thank you for signing up for our newsletter via %s. we'll be in touch" %( 
                                        name,
                                         email)

        send_mail (subject, 
                            contact_message, 
                            from_email, 
                            to_email,
                            fail_silently=False)


    context = {
        "form": form
    }


    return render(request, "signUp.html",context)
```

**This is my html file**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <font color="#4C194C">Newsletter Sign Up</font>
                  <form action=" " method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" name="email">
                  </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Thank you for your time and energy.
N.B I don't want to use {{form.as_p}} method in my html

Answer (score 0):

Tell you the truth I think that you need to improve your code (for example model and form).
Why do you need to hold SignUp model? that's another table that going to be saved on your DB, do you really need it? 
At your form you can just check if email is exists by using `SignUp.objects.exists(email=email)`.

```
    def clean_email(self):
       email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
       match = SignUp.objects.exists(email=email)
       if not match:
           raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already 
                                        subscribed.')
       return email
```

And last thing, after validating your request you can just access request.data with the parameter key.

Comment: thanks alot, I have improved my code as per yours. about the model, I need all the emails to be saved for future purpose like I might want it for sending promotion mail to all. anyhow thanks and let me know if it's possible to integrate my model with html code without using {{form.as_p}}

Comment: @FlimonShferaw I think that it will be more reasonable to hold email, name and that kind of fields on User model (significant names make your code more readable).

Your form need to validate the parameters that sent with the request, therefore you need to use it in your endpoint when handling requests (like you did on first place). You might consider sending back the user after sign-in/sign-up.